# How to add compute-only nodes to Hadoop cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am setting up a cluster with two data+compute nodes and two compute-only nodes with Hadoop. I am using Spark with Yarn for data processing. For the former type of nodes, I can just add the host-name to the workers config and hadoop automatically starts both hdfs and YARN on these nodes. But for the compute-only nodes, I do not want them to run dfs. One way might be to add these to the workers config as well but then exclude/decommission these nodes but I feel like this is not the right way. I cannot find any hadoop config to exclude specific nodes from running dfs. Could someone please let me know the right way to set up this kind of node distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for / against the spirit of standard Hadoop; the idea was to have compute and storage defined.

If you want that, then you need to use Cloud provided solutions such as EMR from AWS where storage and compute has been divorced for elasticity and for billing - i.e. make it attractive for Cloud resources to be dynamic and cheaper.